# Hello Android Test Errors

Tags: android

hi when i run hello Android test http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html

i got the following errors

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.helloandroid/com.ex.helloAndroid.HelloAndroid }
at android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(Instrumentation.java:447)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivityWithIntent(InstrumentationTestCase.java:106)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivity(InstrumentationTestCase.java:84)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.getActivity(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:87)
at com.example.helloandroid.test.HelloAndroidTest.setUp(HelloAndroidTest.java:19)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:164)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:151)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:425)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1520)
```

I did not understand why these errors are coming and give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you haven't specified the Activity name in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".ClassName"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

Something like above mentioned code.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: This error usualy come when you forgot to add the activity in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I mentioned all things but i am getting the same problem